# Restrict delete of master record if it has children

Tags: sql, firebird

How can I restrict delete of a master record if it has children in a Firebird database.

Comment: Add foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a foreign key from the child table to the parent table. The default behavior of a foreign key will prevent deletion of records from the parent table if there are child records.

For example

```
create table parent (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key
);

create table child (
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
    parent_id integer references parent(id)
);
```

This will also prevent you from adding records to child with `parent_id` values (other than `null`) that do not exist in `parent`. You can further modify the behavior of the foreign key constraint using `on update` and `on delete` clauses. See the Firebird language reference on [constraints](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-constraints). For example using `on delete cascade` will delete rows from the child table if the parent record is deleted.

A foreign key can only point to a primary key or a unique key.

The above code is intentionally short, you should consider using named constraints for both primary and foreign key constraints, as it will simplify future maintenance, check the [language reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html) for details.